Equivalent definitions for $O_p$
I know that $Y_n=O_p(X_n)$ is by definition,
$$\lim_{C \rightarrow \infty}\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|Y_n|/|X_n| > C)=0. $$ I want to define a space $A_n$ such that $Y_n\leq C_0|X_n|$ for some fixed positive constant $C_0 > 0$. I want to argue that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(\text{statement related to } A_n)=1$.
My first question is that
1.Is it okay to argue that
$\exists \text{ a sequence } \left\{a_n \right\}_{n \geq 1} $ such that $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }P(|Y_n| \leq C_0 |X_n| a_n)=1$ ?
Differently, I can define an event $A_n$ such that $Y_n\leq C|X_n|$ for some positive constant $C > 0$, so $A_n$ depends on $C$. Then, by definition, $$\lim_{C \rightarrow \infty}\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(A_n(C))=1.$$ My second question is that

Are there some conditions to switch $\lim$ and $\liminf$ each other like
$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{C \rightarrow \infty}P(A_n(C))=1 ?$$

My third question:

If I can use the original definition $A_n$ using a fixed constant $C_0$ and claim that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)=1$, it is best for me. Any recommendation for this?

